# Apply other textbox to fileupload

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

So I'm creating a asp web form myself and basically using a sql database to save files uploaded and are able to download them again. Im using a fileUpload with it which works grand. What im wondering is there anyway i could get say information somewhere else e.g a document file path and then put that into the fileupload1.postedfile etc so i can then upload it from my already build function for that fileupload.

So i have my own file uploading working perfect, uses a simple file upload browse and upload button which then saves it to the sql database as binary etcs.

```
Dim fileName As String = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName)
        Dim fileExtension As String =Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName)
        Dim documentType As String = String.Empty


        Dim uploader As String = Environment.UserName


        'provide document type based on it's extension
        Select Case fileExtension
            Case ".pdf"
                documentType = "application/pdf"
                Exit Select
            Case ".xls"
                documentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
                Exit Select
            Case ".xlsx"
                documentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
                Exit Select
            Case ".doc"
                documentType = "application/vnd.ms-word"
                Exit Select
            Case ".docx"
                documentType = "application/vnd.ms-word"
                Exit Select
            Case ".gif"
                documentType = ".gif"
                Exit Select
            Case ".png"
                documentType = ".png"
                Exit Select
            Case ".jpg"
                documentType = ".jpg"
                Exit Select
            Case ".txt"
                documentType = ".txt"
                Exit Select
            Case ".msg"
                documentType = "application/vnd.ms-outlook"
                Exit Select
            Case ".mht"
                documentType = ".mht"
                Exit Select

        End Select

        'Calculate size of file to be uploaded
        Dim fileSize As Integer = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength



        'Create array and read the file into it
        Dim documentBinary As Byte() = New Byte(fileSize - 1) {}
        FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream.Read(documentBinary, 0, fileSize)
```

My purpose of wanting to do this is i would be given say a .txt file with multiple lines of different file paths. I then want to be able to read through that .txt file (which is not a problem) and then almost have the upload do it automatically where i could basically be like uploadfile1.selectedfile = "c:\example.txt" or so. rather than doing it one at a time.

Please forgive me as I fairly new to fileupload and using binary byte date etcs to store it in sql database.

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons, a web page cannot initiate a file upload automatically. The browser requires a user to select the file to be uploaded.

But there are ways that you can tell an file input control to upload more than 1 file at a time. It's just harder than doing 1 at a time.

Comment: But there is no real way to go about basically reading a .txt file full of file paths and have it upload each?

Comment: Not using the browser.